# multiple video in mpmovieplayer works fine in simulator but get SIGABRT error when running on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

its really frustrated me over 3days, I've check everything and it works just fine. no errors, no warnings on simulator but when launch on iPad, it got this SIGABRT error. I'm using Xcode 4.3 and ARC activate. here is my code :

.h files :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface videothumbnailViewController : UIViewController {
    NSURL *videoURL;
    NSURL *videoURL2;

   MPMoviePlayerController *player;
   MPMoviePlayerController *player2;

    UIScrollView *scrollView;



    }
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *player;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *player2;


-(IBAction)stopmovie:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)playmovie:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)playmovie2:(id)sender;

@end
```

and the implementation file :

```
#import "videothumbnailViewController.h"
#import "MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h"


@interface videothumbnailViewController ()


@end

@implementation videothumbnailViewController
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize player;
@synthesize player2;



-(IBAction)playmovie2:(id)sender {

 // [player stop];


    NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test2.mov" ofType:nil];
   videoURL2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2];
    player2 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL2];
    player2.view.frame = CGRectMake(676, 0, 605, 339);
    player2.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
       [scrollView addSubview:player2.view];
    player2.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [player2.backgroundView addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test2.png"]]];
    player2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [player2 play];
    player2.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;




}

-(IBAction)playmovie:(id)sender {

   [player2 stop];


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test.mov" ofType:nil];
    videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 605, 339);
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [scrollView addSubview:player.view];
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [player.backgroundView addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]]];
    player.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [player play];
    player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;


}

-(IBAction)stopmovie:(id)sender {

    [player stop];


}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test2.mov" ofType:nil];
    videoURL2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2];
    player2 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL2];
    player2.view.frame = CGRectMake(676, 0, 605, 339);
    player2.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [scrollView addSubview:player2.view];
    player2.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    player2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [player2 stop];


    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1300, 339)]; 
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test.mov" ofType:nil];
    videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 605, 339);
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [scrollView addSubview:player.view];
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [player.backgroundView addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]]];
    player.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    [player play];






}



- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add an exception breakpoint like this:

1. Go to breakpoint pane in Xcode and click the plus button at the bottom
   [image]
2. Click Add exception breakpoint
   [image]
3. Click done
   [image]

The debugger should no stop at the line where the exception is thrown.

Hope this helps!

Comment: already did it before and its shows the error, but i just don't know what is the error about(I'm just a beginner) and i really have no clue how to fix it. perhaps you can help me with this?anyway, many thanks in advanced.

Comment: thanks for the input, i just found out that actually its a video file problem. after i change it to another file, its just works. thank you for giving your thought.